# How to get a page slug in WordPress?

Tags: slug

I would like to know if anyone knows how I can get the call to a wordpress slug with a wordpress function. All this in order that everything is added automatically in the following way, EXAMPLE:

```
<link rel = "alternate" hreflang = "fr-BE" href = "https://www.moneytrans.eu/belgium/{{SLUG HERE}}" />
```

As you can see, I only need the function to take the slug of the page without including directories or anything like that.

Thanks for your support!

Comment: If you want to get the post slug of the current page you can use `get_post_field('post_name')`.  
If you want to get the whole page url you can use `get_permalink()`

Comment: Hi @Buttered_Toast Will you have an example of how I can apply it?

Ideally, at the end of the tag: <link rel = "alternate" hreflang = "fr-BE" href = "https://www.moneytrans.eu/belgium/[[SLUG HERE}}" />

In the variable {{SLUG_HERE}} I ​​recognize the function and bring me the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by your link tag and the place you want the slug in, the code would be like this.

```html
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-BE" href="https://www.moneytrans.eu/belgium/<?= get_post_field('post_name'); ?>" />
```

You don't need to add all those spaces in attributes, for example, instead of `rel = "alternate"` do `rel="alternate"`, and so on.

Comment: Hi, this's perfect. Thanks so much!